# Pass PDO result to another temproary table or insert to temp table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello ,

```
             $sql = "select col1 , col2 from table where id=2"; // sometimes query larger
             $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
             $q->execute(array_values($v));
              $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
               while($r = $q->fetch())

               {                
                     echo " $r[$i]";

                }
```

Code is Working Fine.

Now i want To save Query Result to Another Temporary Table.
i Dont know no. of columns generated in Query result. Each time Query is different so columns and data is different. So How store that Query result to another table.

Answer (score 1):

You could let MySQL do that work for you, e.g. via

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl WHERE ...
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html